# Laravel Collection Filter breaking serialization format

Tags: laravel, serialization, laravel-collection

I have a serialized String like this

```
$string = '[{"name":"FOO"},{"name":""},{"name":"BAR"}]';
```

I am trying to process it via Laravel Collection's filter method and eliminate items without a defined "name" property.

```
$collection = collect(\json_decode($string));
$collection = $collection->filter(function($v){
    return !empty($v->name);
});
$string = \json_encode($collection->toArray());
dd($string);
```

Normally I am expecting something like this:

```
[{"name":"FOO"},{"name":"BAR"}]
```

But I'm getting something like this:

```
{"0":{"name":"FOO"},"2":{"name":"BAR"}}
```

Funny thing is, if I skip the filtering process or return true every time, I keep getting the string in the desired format. Removing the `toArray()` call has the same result. I don't want to keep the numeric indices as associative object keys.

Why this anomaly? And what should I do to get the serialized data in desired format?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but can you try this: $string = \json_encode($collection->values());

Comment: Yes, the values() call did the trick for me.  Thanks. Although, I'm still curious why the toArray() didn't work.

Comment: I think the collection adds the index automatically because you have the key name and you can't have the same key for all the elements in array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP arrays the index key must be unique.
In your case you have the key 'name' and collection automatically assigns the index key to all items in the collection.

To overcome that problem just call

```
$string = \json_encode($collection->values());
```